# Как указать через nth-last последний элемент?

Tags: html, css

как указать через nth-last последний элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last-child

Answer (score 0):

Обе записи равносильны:

```
*:nth-last-child(1), *:nth-last-of-type(1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокласс :last-child задает стилевое оформление последнего элемента своего родителя.
http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child

Comment: А разве не это имелось в виду?